# Azure Data-bricks : How to read part files and save it as one file to blob?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Python spark writing a data-frame to a folder in blob which gets saved as part files :

```
df.write.format("json").save("/mnt/path/DataModel")
```

Files are saved as :

[image]

i am using following code to merge it into one file :

```
#Read Part files
 path = glob.glob("/dbfs/mnt/path/DataModel/part-000*.json")  

#Move file to FinalData folder in blbo
    for file in path: 
          shutil.move(file,"/dbfs/mnt/path/FinalData/FinalData.json")
```

> But **FinalData.Json** only have last part file data and not data of all
>   part files.

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to simply merge the content of these files to a file, but due to the description of the `shutil.move` function as the figure below, its feature is like Linux `mv`, so the content of the last file will cover the content of the previous files.

[image]

And the reason of writing multiple files by the code is that Spark working on HDFS, so more than 128MB (HDFS part file size) data writen on HDFS will generate multiple files named with the `part` prefix, please refer to [What is Small file problem in HDFS ?](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/What-is-Small-file-problem-in-HDFS/m-p/200786).

A workaround solution to satisfy your needs is to convert a PySpark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe and then to use pandas dataframe function `to_json` to write a json file.

Here is my sample code.

```
df.toPandas().to_json('/dbfs/mnt/path/FinalData/FinalData.json')
```

And then check if file exists.

```
import os
os.path.isfile('/dbfs/mnt/path/FinalData/FinalData.json')
```

Or

```
dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/mnt/path/')
```

As reference, the figure below is my result.

[image]

For your other question, to read part files using PySpark is to pass a wildcard path to function `spark.read.json()` as the code below.

```
spark.read.json('dbfs:/mnt/path/DataModel/part-*.json')
```

Comment: I have tried using to-pandas, file is getting created but format of json is not proper

Comment: Why And then check if file exists. is needed ?

Comment: @SagarK No for checking a file whether exists, I just want to show you that the file has been created.

Comment: @SagarK May you should show same sample data to me. Let me know what the structure of your dataframe and your json created, and what you want the proper json format is.