# Merge CSV files in ADLS2 that are prepared through DataBricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

While running DataBricks code and preparing CSV files and loading them into ADLS2, the CSV files are split into many  CSV files and are being loaded into ADLS2.

Is there a way to merge these CSV files in ADLS2 thru pyspark.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to merge these CSV files in ADLS2 thru pyspark.

As i know,spark dataframe does makes the files separately.Theoretically,you could use [spark.csv method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) which could accept list of strings as parameters.

[image]

```
>>> df = spark.read.csv('path')
```

Then use [df.toPandas().to_csv()](http://to_csv) method to write objects into `pandas` dataframe.You could refer to some clues from this case:[Azure Data-bricks : How to read part files and save it as one file to blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964745/azure-data-bricks-how-to-read-part-files-and-save-it-as-one-file-to-blob/58968478#58968478).

However,i'm afraid that this process could not hold such high memory consumption. So,i'd suggest you just using `os` package to do the merge job directly.I tested below 2 snippet of code for your reference.

***1st:***

```
import os

path = '/dbfs/mnt/test/'
file_suffix = '.csv'
filtered_files = [file for file in files if file.endswith(file_suffix)]
print(filtered_files)

with open(path + 'final.csv', 'w') as final_file:
    for file in filtered_files:
        with open(file) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            final_file.writelines(lines[1:])
```

***2rd:***

```
import os

path = '/dbfs/mnt/test/'
file_suffix = '.csv'

filtered_files = [os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top=path , topdown=False) for name in files if name.endswith(file_suffix)]
print(filtered_files)

with open(path + 'final2.csv', 'w') as final_file:
    for file in filtered_files:
        with open(file) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            final_file.writelines(lines[1:])
```

The second one is compatible hierarchy.

---

In additional, i provide a way here which is using ADF copy activity to transfer multiple csv files into one file in ADLS gen2.

Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage) and configure the folder path in ADLS gen2 source dataset.Then set MergeFiles with [copyBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-as-a-sink-type) property.(Besides, you could use wildFileName like `*.csv` to exclude files which you don't want to touch in the specific folder)

> Merges all files from the source folder to one file. If the file name
>   is specified, the merged file name is the specified name. Otherwise,
>   it's an autogenerated file name.